# Please explain this Makefile - executable rule appears to be missing

Tags: c++, makefile

I have this makefile which I don't understand.

```
build_sources:=$(wildcard *.cpp)
depends:=$(build_sources:.cpp=.d)
build_targets:=$(build_sources:.cpp=)

.PHONY: all
all: $(build_targets)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(build_targets) *.{a,o,d}

#build the list of header file dependencies automatically
%.d: %.cpp
    @echo building include dependencies for $(*F)
    @$(CXX) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< | { sed 's#\($*\)\.o[ :]*#\1.o $@ : #g' ; echo "%.h:;" ; } > $@

-include $(depends)
```

I understand that the executables created are `build_target`. So if I have `Foo.cpp` and `Bar.cpp`, the executables created would be `Foo` and `Bar`.

But how does it do that? I only see 1 rule, and it is `%.d: %.cpp`. So it's saying the `Foo.d` file depends on `Foo.cpp`. But what about the rule to actually compile `Foo`?

This makefile works, so it's not actually missing anything. But how come I don't see the rule? Is there some implicit rule?

EDIT - i did make debug, and saw the following

```
No need to remake target `foo.d'.
  Considering target file `foo'.
   File `foo' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `foo'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `foo'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `foo.o'.
Found an implicit rule for `foo'.      ## WHAT EXACTLY IS THIS?
Considering target file `foo.o'.
 File `foo.o' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `foo.o'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `foo'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `foo.c'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `foo'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `foo.cc'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `foo'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `foo.C'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `foo'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `foo.cpp'.
 Found an implicit rule for `foo.o'.
  Pruning file `foo.cpp'.
  Pruning file `foo.cpp'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `foo.o'.
Must remake target `foo.o'.
g++   -I../../include -Wall -std=c++11 -O3  -Wsign-compare -Wno-strict-aliasing -s  -c -o foo.o foo.cpp
```

That's great. This must be the rule that's getting called. But where is this rule from? How do I know what default rules exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably miss to understand this `Makefile` is the concept of [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) and [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

This part finds .cpp files:

```
build_sources:=$(wildcard *.cpp)
```

And this part creates targets with the same name (using the variable `build_sources` defined above) except the extension is replaced by .d:

```
depends:=$(build_sources:.cpp=.d)
```

The same kind of construction defines the build targets (same file name with extension removed):

```
build_targets:=$(build_sources:.cpp=)
```

Then the default target is defined to require `build_targets`, i.e the executable corresponding to the .cpp`

```
all: $(build_targets)
```

This rule defines how to build a `.d` from a `.cpp`:

```
#build the list of header file dependencies automatically
%.d: %.cpp
    @echo building include dependencies for $(*F)
    @$(CXX) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< | { sed 's#\($*\)\.o[ :]*#\1.o $@ : #g' ; echo "%.h:;" ; } > $@
```

`gcc -MM` produce rules to know on which headers a `.c` or `.cpp` file depend. Typically if `test.cpp` includes `test1.h` and `test2.h` the output will be:

```
test.o: test.cpp test1.h test2.h
```

The .d will contain dependencies of each cpp file and will create a ruleto build a `.o` file and an executable from each cpp. `$@` is the target of the rule (the `.d` file) and will contain, unless I'm mistaken, a rule looking like this (written by the sed expression):

```
filename.o filename.d : filename.cpp <list of headers>
%.h:;
```

The first rule give dependencies of the `.o` files. It has no recipe which means it simply adds dependencies to any existing rule. An implicit rule will be used to build them.
The second one is here in case you suppress a header. In this case, `make` will use this rule that says that there's simply nothing to do (it has an empty recipe).

Then all the `.d` files are included as part of the makefile:

```
-include $(depends)
```

Finally, the [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) to link a single `.o` file kicks in:

> Linking a single object file
>
> n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

**Edit:** To build objects in a subdirectory `obj` you would have to modify each filename:

```
depends:=$(foreach file,$(build_sources:.cpp=.d),"obj/$(file)")
```

To build binaries in a separate subdirectory `bin` you would need to do the same for build_targets:

```
build_targets:=$(foreach file,$(build_sources:.cpp=), "bin/$(file)")
```

Then you need to write the rule to build it because the default rule wont work anymore (the `.o` is not in the same directory). What you want is to add a rule like this:

```
bin/foo: obj/foo.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) obj/foo.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o bin/foo
```

which can be done with the right modification of the long shell command:

```
    @$(CXX) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< | { sed 's#\($*\)\.o[ :]*#\1.o $@ : #g' ; echo "%.h:;" ; obj=`echo $< | sed 's/.cpp/.o/'` ; bin=`echo $< | sed 's/.cpp//'` ; echo "$bin: $obj" ; echo -e "\t\$(CC) \$(LDFLAGS) $obj \$(LOADLIBES) \$(LDLIBS) -o $bin" ; } > $@
```

Comment: Right. But the rule to build a `.d` isn't enough, since it makes `Foo.d`, and not `Foo`, which is what's actually being generated.

Comment: I looked up implicit rules (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) and saw this "Linking a single object file
n is made automatically from n.o by running the linker (usually called ld) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is ‘$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)’.

This rule does the right thing for a simple program with only one source file. "    Is this it?

Comment: I'm updating with more details. In fact, the .d will be included in the makefile and contain rules to build the files

Comment: Now it's complete ! Sorry for the hick-up :-)

Comment: as a follow up question - how do i change the makefile so that the output gets build in a separate build directory?

Comment: Only the executables or also the `.o` ? You'd have to modify the rules. I update the answer for better readability

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105304/discussion-between-user3240688-and-colin-pitrat).

Answer (score 0):

Your make package includes a large number of default rules, which this Makefile depends on. Try running your make with -d (debug info). I believe that will show you everything that is in play.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile is't complete in itself. It automatically creates the files `.d` which are snippets included into that makefile at the end. *These files are created with the `%.d`-rule.*

So have a look at those generated `.d` files to see rules for each individual object file. The rule generation script is written with `sed` and kind of hard to read, but in fact very simple. At first, the compiler is invoked on the `.cpp` file with the `-MM` flag, which will output something like

```
foo.o: foo.cpp foo.h bar.h
```

if `foo.cpp` includes its own header file `foo.h` as well as `bar.h`, for example (directly or indirectly).

The `sed` regex replacement command now simply adds the name of the file, in which the generated rules are about to be written (the `.d` file) right after the `.o` in the above rule, so it is also marked as depending on the sources, just like the object file. That's important when the includes in one of the sources is changed later. The `sed` command also adds a rule for all header files to do nothing.

```
foo.o foo.d: foo.cpp foo.h bar.h
%.h:;
```

The resulting object files `.o` are then linked using one of the [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html):

> #### Linking a single object file
>
> n is made automatically from n.o by
>   running the linker (usually called `ld`) via the C compiler. The precise
>   recipe used is `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)`.
>
> [...]

Comment: Almost right - the `sed` command makes _the expansion of_ `$@` depend on the same things as the object file (in this case, the written line is `foo.o foo.d : foo.cpp foo.h bar.h`) so that the dependency file is rebuilt if any of the relevant sources change.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you for your explanation. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Many rules are *built in* to Make.  If you are using GNU Make, you can get it to print its built-in rules like this:

```
make -f /dev/null -p
```

You can make it ignore the built-in rules with `-r`; if you do this with your Makefile, you'll find that it complains that it doesn't know how to make your targets.